# Import data into pdf form table from csv using PHP

Tags: php, pdf-form

I have a PDF form with a table where multiple students information is to filled, as shown in the screen screenshot.

The traditional  way to do is open PDF with acrobat and go to Form > Manage Form Data > Import Data.

Can we do it using PHP? Is it possible? Any hint, thanks in advance.

I have searched the internet but everywhere it is being told to fill the form fields. Couldn't find any solution specifying filling data into table.

[image]